# Custom Header Names & Formula for Filtered Data from Excel Table in One Cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Google Sheets, I can create custom header names in one cell and then also append a formula in that same cell so that both the header names and formula are all in one cell.

For example, in [cell A1 in Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C4462wI3xSboBRdtz60PtBtTiKJfMtbE9CKH9df3h_w/edit#gid=0&range=A1), I can create the following formula...

```
={{"Date", "Pursuit Lead", "Stage", "Description"};query(Sheet2!A2:D,"select * where Col1 is not null",0)}
```

Regardless of what the headers are named from the Sheet2 tab I'm querying data from, I can create custom header names in Sheet1 for cells A1, B1, C1 and D1, while at the same time creating the formula, and all into the same cell, in A1.

**Is there a similar way to do this in Excel, to where I can create custom header names for data I'm referencing from a table in another tab while placing the formula in the same cell without using a VBA Script?**

Comment: Look into VSTACK and HSTACK

Comment: `=VSTACK({"Date", "Pursuit Lead", "Stage", "Description"},FILTER(Sheet2!A2:D10000,Sheet2!A2:A10000<>""))`

Comment: Perfect, that works great, @ScottCraner. Thanks so much! For any Google Sheets users who are needing to know how to do this in Excel...take note!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Scott Craner's comment, which gave me the answer, I was able to type in the following custom headers with VSTACK as an equivalent to what I can do in Google Sheets. Use the following as a starter for your Excel formula.

***This allows you to create custom header names when referencing tables or data elsewhere in Excel.***

**Excel Version**

```
=VSTACK({"Date", "Pursuit Lead", "Stage", "Description"},YOUR FORMULA HERE)
```

**Google Sheets Version**

```
={{"Date", "Pursuit Lead", "Stage", "Description"};YOUR FORMULA HERE}
```

Thank you, Scott!